# Allowing User to Download Image from my S3 Bucket

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3, uri

I am trying to construct a method which will allow a user to download a pdf file from my s3 bucket, (which at the moment it does)

But some parts of the url may change from time to time, like the id number after /timetables, the filename (but will always be a pdf) and the id number after the filename

This is what i have so far

```
def download
  path = "images/timetables/14/original.pdf?"
  data = open("http://#{ENV['AWS_BUCKET']}.s3.amazonaws.com/#{path}/1392904333") 
  send_data data.read, filename: 'Timetable',
                       type: 'application/pdf', 
                       disposition: 'attachment', 
                       stream: 'true', 
                       buffer_size: '4096'

end
```

is there a way to get this information on the fly or can i only hardcode it? Ideally i want to store as much as the path into variables as i can.

Could anyone show me how to do this correctly please.

Thanks

Comment: Could you explain the problem again? Why does the filename change? What triggers the change? Does only name change or also the contents? Is it a security feature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It'll be easier to use [paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) to manage the uploading. Using this you'll create a table to save a record which will have a dynamic reference to your uploaded file on [S3](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/wiki/Paperclip-with-Amazon-S3).

The workflow goes like this:

- You upload the PDF in question to your app
- paperclip uploads it to S3 and saves the URL to your database
- you provide a link to your users for the S3 URL of the PDF
- OR you give them the link to your record and you initiate the download as you posted above

First the model which will hold the pdf file reference looks like this:

```
class PdfRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :pdf, :storage => :s3,
    :bucket => 'S3_BUCKET_NAME',
    :s3_credentials => {
      :access_key_id => 'AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID',
      :secret_access_key => 'AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'
    }
end
```

Create a form for yourself to upload your pdf:

```
# app/views/pdf_records/new
<%= form_for @pdf_record, multipart: true do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :pdf %>
  <%= f.file_field :pdf %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Using this form you can upload the pdf and paperclip will save it to S3 and keep a reference to it in your database.

Give your users a link to your `pdf_record` like this:

```
@pdf_record = PdfRecord.find(which ever one you want)
@pdf_record.pdf.url # => the S3 url
```

Giving your users that url will let them download the pdf directly however, if you want to hide the URL and also allow you to update the pdf without breaking the link you can give the users a link to the `pdf_record` and then you initiate the download from your controller:

```
# give your users this url, as defined in your routes.rb
pdf_record_url(@pdf_record)
```

Then in the show action of the pdf_record controller:

```
def show
  pdf_record = PdfRecord.find(params[:id])
  data = open(pdf_record.pdf.url) 
  send_data data.read, filename: pdf_record.pdf_file_name,
                       type: pdf_record.pdf_content_type, 
                       disposition: 'attachment', 
                       stream: 'true', 
                       buffer_size: '4096'
end
```

Now, you can update that `pdf_record` whenever you want and since your users have a link to the record rather than the actual pdf file the link will always work.

Comment: Thank you for such an in depth answer, I am using paperclip already so i will try this later